# type error when running es6 code using gulp and babel

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have the below es6 class which is in mqttModule.js.

```
/*jshint esversion: 6*/
import mqtt from 'mqtt';

let client;

class MqttWrapper {

    constructor(mqttOptions) {
        this.clientId = mqttOptions.clientId;
        this.keepAlive = mqttOptions.keepAlive;
        this.clean = mqttOptions.clean;
        this.reconnectPeriod = mqttOptions.reconnectPeriod;
        this.will = mqttOptions.lastWillMessage;

        let options = {
            clientId: this.clientId,
            keepAlive: this.keepAlive,
            clean: this.clean,
            reconnectPeriod: this.reconnectPeriod,
            will: this.will
        };

        client = mqtt.connect(url, options);
    }
}

export {MqttWrapper};
```

and I am calling it as shown below.

```
import MqttWrapper from './mqttModule'

let willMessage = {
  topic : 'WillMessage',
  payload : 'This is the last will message',
  qos : 2,
  retain : 'true'
}

let mqttOptions = {
  clientId : '101',
  keepAlive : 10,
  clean : 'false',
  reconnectPeriod : '1000',
  lastWillMessage : willMessage
}

let mqttWrapperObj = new MqttWrapper(mqttOptions);
```

When I run the gulp command it transpiles fine without any errors. But when I run it, I am getting the error saying type error. Below is the full trace.

```
G:\Projects\Kube2\edge-node-sdk-js-test\src\app.js:25
var mqttWrapperObj = new _mqttModule2.default(mqttOptions);
                     ^

TypeError: _mqttModule2.default is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:19:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at loader (G:\Projects\Kube2\edge-node-sdk-js-test\node_modules\babel-cli\no
de_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:158:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (G:\Projects\Kube
2\edge-node-sdk-js-test\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-register\lib\n
ode.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at G:\Projects\Kube2\edge-node-sdk-js-test\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\_babel
-node.js:171:48
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Projects\Kube2\edge-node-sdk-js-test\node_modules\
babel-cli\lib\_babel-node.js:172:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! edge-node-sdk-js-test@1.0.0 start: `babel-node --presets es2015 ./src/a
pp.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the edge-node-sdk-js-test@1.0.0 start script 'babel-node --pr
esets es2015 ./src/app.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the edge-node-sdk-js-test package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     babel-node --presets es2015 ./src/app.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs edge-node-sdk-js-test
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls edge-node-sdk-js-test
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     G:\Projects\Kube2\edge-node-sdk-js-test\npm-debug.log
```

Below is my gulp file just incase.

```
        /*jshint esversion: 6 */

const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('es6',() => {
  return gulp.src('src/app.js')
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('default',['es6'],() => {
  gulp.watch('src/app.js',['es6'])
});
```

And below is the transpiled app.js file that gets created when I run the gulp command.

```
        'use strict';

var _mqttModule = require('./mqttModule');

var _mqttModule2 = _interopRequireDefault(_mqttModule);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

var willMessage = {
  topic: 'WillMessage',
  payload: 'This is the last will message',
  qos: 2,
  retain: 'true'
}; /*jshint esversion: 6*/


var mqttOptions = {
  clientId: '101',
  keepAlive: 10,
  clean: 'false',
  reconnectPeriod: '1000',
  lastWillMessage: willMessage
};

var mqttWrapperObj = new _mqttModule2.default(mqttOptions);
```

I am new to ES6 and babel stuff. Please advice.

Comment: Does `./myModule2` exist? Or is that some kind of partially transpiled file that was created mid transpile?

Comment: I only have the mqttModule.js and app.js. When I run the 'gulp' command, a transpiled version of the app.js gets created in the 'build' folder. That's all I have

Comment: @NickZuber sorry I posted the wrong transpiled class. Let me edit

Comment: Try changing `export {MqttWrapper};` to `export default MqttWrapper;` and let me know if that changes anything.